# Setting mail template in ses client

Tags: email, amazon-web-services, templates, cakephp-3.0, amazon-ses

I am developing a web application using cakephp 3.0 and I have an email sending function earlier I was use php mail function. Now I am using AWS ses client. So in that ses client how I can render a template. In cake php email function it was possible. But I don't know how to do it in aws ses client.
 My code is

```
 public function testMail() {

if ($this->request->is('post')) {

  $client = SesClient::factory(Configure::read('AWScredentials'));


  $formData = $this->request->data;
  $body = $formData['body'];
  $ToAddresses = $formData['ToAddresses'];
  $request = array();
  $request['Source'] = 's@gmail.com';
  $request['Destination']['ToAddresses'] = array($ToAddresses);
  $request['Destination']['CcAddresses'] = 'ss@gmail.com';
  $request['Message']['Subject']['Data'] = 'Test mail from vcollect ses';
  $request['Message']['Subject']['Charset'] = 'ISO-2022-JP';
  $request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Data'] = $body;
  $request['Message']['Body']['Text']['Charset'] = 'ISO-2022-JP';

  try {
    $result = $client->sendEmail($request);
    $messageId = $result->get('MessageId');
    $this->log("Email sent! Message ID: $messageId", "info");
  } catch (Exception $e) {
    $this->log("The email was not sent. Error message:" . $e->getMessage(), "error");
  }
}   }
```

Comment: If you don't share some details about what's going wrong with your code, there's pretty much no way anyone can help you. An error message, at the very very least.

Comment: I am not getting any errors, I want to render an  email template and include that in  body of ses

Answer (score 1):

**You must create a debug sender in app.php, just add it to your EmailTransport array like this, it's allow you to do a fake email without send it**

```
 'EmailTransport' => [
        'default' => [
            'className' => 'Mail',
            // The following keys are used in SMTP transports
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'port' => 25,
            'timeout' => 30,
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'secret',
            'client' => null,
            'tls' => null,
            'url' => env('EMAIL_TRANSPORT_DEFAULT_URL', null),
        ],
        'debug' => [
            'className' => 'Debug',
        ],
    ],
```

**after to generate the email with your your template you can use this function for exemple**

```
public function setTemplate($template,$layout = null,$viewVars = array(),$debug = 0)
    {
        if(empty($layout)) $layout = 'default';

        $Email = new Email();
        $Email->template($template, $layout)
        ->transport('debug') //<---- Allows you to simulate the message without sending it
        ->to(array('foo@bar.org'=>'toto'))
        ->emailFormat('html');
        ->viewVars($viewVars);


        $Email->send();


        /* Once email is generate, personally i duplicate the object for access to the protected proprety ( it's not very clean but i don't have a greatest solution)
        The idea is to get _htmlMessage in the object */


        $refObj  = new ReflectionObject($Email);
        $refProp1 = $refObj->getProperty('_htmlMessage');
        $refProp1->setAccessible(TRUE);

        if($debug == 1)
        {
            die(debug($refProp1->getValue($Email)));
        }

        return $refProp1->getValue($Email);   // <---- your html code 
    }
```

Comment: I dont want to use cakephp mail function I want to use amazon ses client amazon ses api to send mail

Comment: Debug sender is do for that, it's don't send the email with cake or what ever.

It's allow you to generate the body of your email with cake template and layout. (that's what you want ? )

So once the html is generated, you're get it and send it with amazon

Comment: @Gransfall The debug transport is ment for debugging purposes in the development and/or testing process, technically you're misusing it. Also note that you can access the message content via the `Email::message()` method, there's no need for these reflection hacks. Furthermore rendering via the `Email` class applies possible charset conversion and line wrapping, that's something one may need to be aware of, depending on the requirements of the API used for processing the data.

Comment: @ndm Thank you for all this information, I will test this as soon as I can